# Facebook Graph - No Auth needed if real user?

Tags: facebook, json, http, facebook-graph-api, xmlhttprequest

I was just trying to work around a little bit with Facebook Graph and it's JSON responses, and I realized, that if I open this URL over Microsoft.XMLHTTP I get an OAuthException. But if I open this url just out of my browser, it opens the JSON file just fine.

Does Facebook read what your HTTP header is and then requires specific headers for an authentication?

I was trying it over this URL:
http://graph.facebook.com/426148244069770/photos?limit=10

Maybe you guys know why this is happening? Since I would really like to read out this JSON over server-side and not force it to the client.

Best,
S.